# How to get the real part of a complex expression

Tags: complex

I am trying to get the real part of this expression given below. Using the `Re` command does not lead anywhere.

```
1/((2.6881 - 0.686385 I) E^(I x))^(
 2/3) E^(-4 I x) ((0.00256727 + 
     0.000818759 I) + (0.00123498 + 
      0.000591567 I) ((2.6881 - 0.686385 I) E^(I x))^(2/3) + 
   E^(I x) ((0.00382662 - 
        0.00012753 I) + (0.00382139 + 
         0.000909473 I) ((2.6881 - 0.686385 I) E^(I x))^(2/3) + 
      E^(I x) ((0.0108048 - 
           0.00264035 I) + (0.0327023 - 0.0135913 I) E^(
          I x) + (0.0119219 + 
            0.000622502 I) ((2.6881 - 0.686385 I) E^(I x))^(
          2/3) + (0.0181462 + 0.00991331 I) ((2.6881 - 0.686385 I) E^(
            I x))^(5/3))))
```

The expression looks like this: 
[image]

Can you please help me get the real part of the above expression as Polynomial of x. I tried specifying `x` is real too, still no luck.

Edit: 
I tried using ComplexExpand as suggested in the first comment but it complicates the expression even further by introducing `Arg` terms.

Here is how the partial output after ComplexExpand looks like (The actual output is too long):

[image]

Comment: Look at `ComplexExpand`

Comment: @LukasLang I added the output after ComplexExpand in the question as a picture. It is even complex.

Comment: Did you use `CompexExpand[Re[expr]]`?

Comment: `Re[expr]` is only evaluated if expr is a  numeric quantity!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear[expr, expr2]

expr[x_] = 
  1/((2.6881 - 0.686385 I) E^(I x))^(2/3) E^(-4 I x) ((0.00256727 + 
       0.000818759 I) + (0.00123498 + 
        0.000591567 I) ((2.6881 - 0.686385 I) E^(I x))^(2/3) + 
     E^(I x) ((0.00382662 - 
          0.00012753 I) + (0.00382139 + 
           0.000909473 I) ((2.6881 - 0.686385 I) E^(I x))^(2/3) + 
        E^(I x) ((0.0108048 - 
             0.00264035 I) + (0.0327023 - 
              0.0135913 I) E^(I x) + (0.0119219 + 
              0.000622502 I) ((2.6881 - 0.686385 I) E^(I x))^(2/
               3) + (0.0181462 + 
              0.00991331 I) ((2.6881 - 0.686385 I) E^(I x))^(5/3))));

expr2[x_] = 
 expr[x] // Rationalize[#, 0] & // Re // 
   ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // FullSimplify

(* (Cos[2/3 ArcTan[
       537620 Cos[x] + 137277 Sin[x], -137277 Cos[x] + 
        537620 Sin[x]]] (10 (3270230 Cos[x] + 1080480 Cos[2 x] + 
         382662 Cos[3 x] + 256727 Cos[4 x] - 1359130 Sin[x] - 
         264035 Sin[2 x] - 12753 Sin[3 x]) + 
      818759 Sin[4 x]))/(100000 5^(2/3) 307880239129^(
    1/3)) + (1111662950087 Cos[x] + 
    80 (2980475000 Cos[2 x] + 955347500 Cos[3 x] + 
       308745000 Cos[4 x] + 3548172281 Sin[x] + 
       250 (622502 Sin[2 x] + 909473 Sin[3 x] + 591567 Sin[4 x])))/
  20000000000000 - ((13591300 Cos[x] + 2640350 Cos[2 x] + 
      127530 Cos[3 x] - 818759 Cos[4 x] + 32702300 Sin[x] + 
      10804800 Sin[2 x] + 3826620 Sin[3 x] + 2567270 Sin[4 x]) Sin[
     2/3 ArcTan[
       537620 Cos[x] + 137277 Sin[x], -137277 Cos[x] + 
        537620 Sin[x]]])/(100000 5^(2/3) 307880239129^(1/3)) *)
```

**EDIT:** Looking at a plot of the real part

```
plt = Plot[expr2[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, MaxRecursion -> 5, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image]

The real part is periodic

```
FunctionPeriod[expr2[x], x]

(* 2 π *)
```

Verifying,

```
expr2[x] == expr2[x + 2 Pi] // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the definition

```
z = 1/((2.6881 - 0.686385 I) E^(I x))^(2/3) E^(-4 I x) ((0.00256727 + 
  0.000818759 I) + (0.00123498 + 
   0.000591567 I) ((2.6881 - 0.686385 I) E^(I x))^(2/3) + 
E^(I x) ((0.00382662 - 
     0.00012753 I) + (0.00382139 + 
      0.000909473 I) ((2.6881 - 0.686385 I) E^(I x))^(2/3) + 
   E^(I x) ((0.0108048 - 
        0.00264035 I) + (0.0327023 - 
         0.0135913 I) E^(I x) + (0.0119219 + 
         0.000622502 I) ((2.6881 - 0.686385 I) E^(I x))^(2/
          3) + (0.0181462 + 
         0.00991331 I) ((2.6881 - 0.686385 I) E^(I x))^(5/3))))
```

Mathematica evaluates

```
expr=Expand[ ExpToTrig[PowerExpand[z  ]]  ]
```

an expression which seems to be `linear in I`. Now you have only to collect for the imaginary unit.

```
rez=Chop@Simplify[Expand[ ExpToTrig[PowerExpand[expr  ]]  ] /.Complex[re_, im_] -> re + ii im /. ii -> 0]
(*0.0555831 Cos[x] + 0.0174754 Cos[(5 x)/3] + 0.0119219 Cos[2 x] + 
0.0056184 Cos[(8 x)/3] + 0.00382139 Cos[3 x] + 
0.00192195 Cos[(11 x)/3] + 0.00123498 Cos[4 x] + 
0.00121345 Cos[(14 x)/3] + 0.0141927 Sin[x] + 
0.001245 Cos[x] Sin[x] - 0.00404056 Sin[(5 x)/3] - 
0.000410898 Sin[(8 x)/3] + 0.000909473 Sin[3 x] + 
0.000257826 Sin[(11 x)/3] + 0.000591567 Sin[4 x] + 
0.000624645 Sin[(14 x)/3]*)
```

gives the real part you are asking for. Sorry for the last code line, I didn't find an easier way...

Comment: `Complex[re_, im_] -> re + ii im /. ii -> 0` can be simplified to `Complex[re_, im_] -> re`